# Implicit types in function calls in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I quite like Swift, but I like seeing my implicit types. How do I do them in a function call? I've tried all these ways:

```
print(String "Hello")
print(String: "Hello")
print([String] "Hello")
print([String "Hello"])
print([[String] "Hello"])
```

but none seem to work (they all throw errors on the lines of seperator expected). Does anyone know how to do this? I've Googled around and have not found very much.

Comment: How about `print(String("Hello"))`?

Comment: @Swipesight I know, but that is basically telling the thing to make a string out of what is already a string. That "Hello" at the end of the chain is still being inferred as a string. I want something like they do for variables `var x: String = "I am x` where it overrides the automatic inference and treats it as a string no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift is a strongly typed language, and (except when bridging) it doesn't do any implicit conversion between types (such as from `Bool` to `Int`, or from `Int16` to `Int`). So really you don't need to tell the compiler that a string is a string.

However if you want to convert a literal to another type, such as a `String` to `NSString`, or a `Int` to `UInt`, just use the `as` operator:

```
print("nsstring" as NSString)
print(10 as UInt)
```

Note that using the `as` operator makes sense only if the function expects a generic parameter or `AnyObject`/`Any`. If a function expects `UInt` and you pass an explicit `Int`, it won't compile:

```
func test(param: UInt) { print(param)}

test(10 as Int) // Error: Int is not convertible to UInt
```

However if you pass a `Int` literal to a function expecting a `UInt`, type inference automatically does the conversion transparently:

```
test(10) // 10 is a Int literal, but it's implicitly converted to UInt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
print(String("Hello"))
```

Actually this would be to covert something into a string format, but there is no other way to show what you would like to see.